# Other Idea to show an inequality $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\geq \sqrt n$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality, alternative-proof, big-list

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\geq \sqrt n$$
I want to prove this by Induction 
$$n=1 \checkmark\\
n=k \to \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt k}\geq \sqrt k\\
n=k+1 \to \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}}\geq \sqrt {k+1}$$ so $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt k}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}}\geq \sqrt k+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}}$$now we prove that $$\sqrt k+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}} >\sqrt{k+1} \\\sqrt{k(k+1)}+1 \geq k+1 \\ k(k+1) \geq k^2 \\k+1 \geq k \checkmark$$ and the second method like below ,

and I want to know is there more Idia to show this proof  ? forexample  combinatorics proofs  , or using integrals ,or fourier series ,....

Is there a close form for this summation ?

any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining [AM-HM](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM) $$\left(a_1+a_2+...+a_n\right)\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\geq n^2$$
Thus 
$$\left(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\geq n^2$$
and
$$n\sqrt{n}\geq\left(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}\right)$$
so
$$n\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\geq n^2$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \sqrt{n}$$

Comment: That's kind of perverse to use $\sqrt k\le\sqrt n$ to get $n\sqrt n$ and not use it for $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ as in Khosrotash solution.

Comment: @zwim as long as it works

Answer (score 30):

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\\+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\\+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\\ \vdots\\+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\end{cases}  \\\\$$

sum of left hands  is $\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ sum of the right hands is $n\times \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$ so 
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n} \geq n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n} \checkmark$$

Comment: For an alternative interpretation of the same concept, divide by $n$ and observe that the LHS is the mean value and the RHS is the minimum value of the function $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $[n]$

Comment: Great answer! +1

Answer (score 18):

Integrals:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt n}\ge\int_1^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt x}\ dx=2\sqrt{n+1}-2$$

And it's very easy to check that

$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\ge\sqrt n$$

for $n\ge2$.

A visuallization of this argument:

[image]

From the red lines down, that area represents a sum.  From the blue line down, that represents an integral.  Clearly, the integral is smaller than the sum.

Comment: :Is there a visual explanation for that proof ?

Comment: Of course.  Give me a few moments...

Comment: thanks a lot .it was interesting

Comment: No problem.  The few moments are over :-)

Comment: maybe the integral could be from 1 to n+1.

Comment: @ChenJiang Lol, I drew the picture, and yet I didn't immediately see.  Thanks for the catch, though it is unnecessary for this.

Comment: (+1) for this approach as the methodology has wide spread application including the leading term of the EMSF.  And congratulations on earning another badge.

Comment: Interestingly we can obtain the same bound without appealing to integrals.  I've posted a solution herein and would like to hear your thoughts.  ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 13):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a simple approach that yields a much tighter bound than requested in the OP, and that relies on nothing more than telescoping series and straightforward arithmetic.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

We begin with the telescoping series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)=\sqrt{n+1}-1 \tag 1$$

---

Inasmuch as $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$, we can write $(1)$ as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\right)=\sqrt{n+1}-1 \tag 2$$

---

Then, using $\sqrt{k+1}>\sqrt k$, we have the inequality

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}\right)>\sqrt{n+1}-1$$

from which we see that

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}> 2(\sqrt {n+1}-1)} \tag 3$$

---

Note that $(3)$ provides a much tighter bound for the summation of interest than the one requested in the OP since

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}>2(\sqrt {n+1} -1)> \sqrt n $$

for $n\ge 2$.  It's easy to see that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt k} = \sqrt n $ for $n=1$.

And we are done!

> **Tools Used:  Telescoping Series and straightforward arithmetic**

Comment: (+1) I find answers such as this very appealing. What made you think of telescoping?

Comment: @Plopperzz Thank you!  Much appreciative.  If we use the first term of the EMSF it is $2(\sqrt n - 1)$.  This looks like the result of a telescoping series.  -Mark

Comment: (+1) very nicely done.  Very nice use of the difference of two squares.

Comment: (+1) Nice. though too much yellow for my taste. A little typo at the end, should be $\ge \sqrt n$.

Comment: @simplybeautifulart Thank you!  I really  it!  I thought it might be instructive to show a way forward using pre-calculus tools only.

Comment: @zwim Thank you for the comment and for catching the typo.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: "I really it!" Many typos?  XD. Cheers

Comment: "I really appreciate it."  And now we see the hazard from using a "not-so-smart" phone to post here.

Comment: Dear Mark, what is EMSF? Thanks.

Comment: @ovi EMSF is an acronym for the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.

Answer (score 7):

By the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases) the harmonic mean is no larger than the quadratic mean:

$$
\require{cancel}
\cfrac{n}{\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \;\le\; \sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{1})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+\cdots+(\sqrt{n})^2}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\cancel{n}(n+1)}{2\,\cancel{n}}}
$$

$$
\implies \quad \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \;\ge\; \sqrt{\frac{2\,n^2}{n+1}} \;\ge\; \sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: Nice one, I compared $M_0$ and $M_1$ while comparing $M_{-1}$ and $M_2$ was bringing the result directly.

Answer (score 5):

Using arithmetic and geometric means inequality :

$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+..+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\ge n\,\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\sqrt 1\sqrt 2..\sqrt n}}\ge n\,(n!)^{-\frac1{2n}}}$

We can get an asymptotic result using Stirling formula :

$n\,(n!)^{-\frac1{2n}}\sim n\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}({\frac ne})^n\right)^{-\frac1{2n}}=\frac{\sqrt e}{\sqrt[4n]{2\pi}}\times n^{1-\frac1{4n}}\times\sqrt n=C(n)\sqrt n$ with $C(n)\to \sqrt[4]e$

Since $\sqrt[4]e\ge 1$ then $C(n)\sqrt n\ge\sqrt n$ for some $n$.

It is not as good as in the other methods, but it presents another idea.

Comment: One may acquire exact inequalities by noting that:$$n!=\exp\left[\sum\ln(k)\right]\le\exp\left[\int\ln(x)\ dx\right]=e\sqrt n\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but since the $n!$ is raised to a negative power, we must find an upper bound, which flips to a lower bound, which then provides what we need quite nicely.

Comment: Yes, nice one :p