# Prove that $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

*Anyone who can solve it or give me an idea on how to try to do it myself?*

$$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \sqrt{n}, \;\;\;n \in \mathbb{N^*}$$

Comment: Maybe try induction.

Comment: This question looks very familiar. Second, the inequality should be $\ge$.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: It might help to know that $\sqrt{n+1} \le \sqrt n + \frac {1}{2\sqrt n}$

Comment: Shouldn't the sign be the other way around?

Comment: Many ideas there, and the inequality is wrong way. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149448/other-idea-to-show-an-inequality-dfrac1-sqrt-1-dfrac1-sqrt-2-dfrac1/2149480#2149480

Comment: yes its >= i m gonna edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality should be the other way around. To solve it multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n}$ and note that the RHS is $n$ and on the LHS you have $n$ terms each greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we multiply both sides by $\sqrt n$, we obtain,:

$\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}2}+\cdots + 1\ge n$.

Each term on the left is at least $1$, and there are $n$ of them, so the sum is greater than or equal to $n$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

we have $ 1<\sqrt n, \sqrt 2 < \sqrt n ... \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt 1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} ...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}*n = \sqrt n$

Answer (score 0):

The denominators of the terms on the left are increasing, so the smallest term on the left is $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus

$$\frac1{1}+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$\geq
\frac1{\sqrt{n}} + \frac1{\sqrt{n}} + \cdots + \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$= n\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}$$