# How to show that $a_n=1+1/\sqrt{2}+\cdots+(1/\sqrt{n-1})-2\sqrt{n}$ has an upper bound.

Tags: induction, monotone-functions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a_n=1+1/\sqrt{2}+\cdots+(1/\sqrt{n-1})-2\sqrt{n}$ while   $a_1=-2,n\ge2 $ ,
I need to prove that $a_n$ converges.
I proved that it is monotonically increasing and tried to prove that it is upper-bounded by induction but failed to.

Also, it was told that $a_n$ converges to $-2<L<-1$ so I tried to show by induction that $a_n$ is bounded by $-1$, but I'm always stuck with $a_{n+1} \le -1 + 1/\sqrt{n}$ or something like that.
How can I prove that $a_n$ is bounded from above?

Comment: You can use Mark Viola idea here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149448/other-idea-to-show-an-inequality-dfrac1-sqrt-1-dfrac1-sqrt-2-dfrac1/2149480#2149480 , just reverse the inequality by using  $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}$ instead in the final argument.

Comment: So $a_1 = -2; a_2 =1-2\sqrt 2; a_3 = 1 + \frac 1{\sqrt 2} - 2\sqrt 3$ etc.  If you have $a_{n+1} \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt n} \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt 2} < 0$ for $n \ge 2$ that's enought to show it is bounded above (by 0!) and if it is monotically increasing it must converge.  I don't see anywhere in the question that you must find what it converges *to* or what the *least* upper bound is.  So you *are* done.  However, if you do have to figure out the value of the limit, you do have more work to do.  But *DO* you have to find the value of the limit?

Comment: Where the "-1" came from? You show by the induction that $a_n<0$ , you cant use -1.
Am I missing something?

Comment: "Where the "-1" came from?"  Uh.... from you?  You said  "I'm always stuck with $a_{n+1} \le - 1 + \frac 1{\sqrt n}$ or something like that".  If you you got that then that's just fine and you are done.  But I don't know how you got $a_{n+1} \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt n}$.  All I know is that you claimed you did.  I'm just saying that if you did.  You are actually done.

Comment: Yes, because I tried to prove $a_n<-1$ in that case I used -1.But if you show for $a_n<0$ you cant use what I wrote because it is wrong in that case

Comment: Why is it wrong? $a_i$ is bounded above.  It doesn't matter by what.  Are you being asked to prove that it converges to a value between -2 and -1.  Well, okay.  If $a_n < -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}}$ *AND* $a_i$ is increasing then $a_n < a_{M} < -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt {M-1}}$ and $M$ can be as large we want.  so $a_n \le \lim a_{M} \le -1 + \lim \frac 1{\sqrt{M-1} = -1 + 0 = -1$.  So you *can* prove $a_n \le -1$ if you want.

Comment: I need to show that $a_n$ is bounded and monotonically increases so you can show that it is converges. And the way you tried to show that $a_n$ is bounded- wrong.

Comment: No.  It is isn't wrong.  It's inefficient but not wrong.  Any way proving $a_i < -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt i}$ is enough to prove that $a_i \le -1$, as the $a_i$ are *increasing* and $\frac 1{\sqrt i}$ are *decreasing* then  all $a_n \le \lim -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt i} = -1$.

Comment: 1)  $a_{n+1} < -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}$.  2) $a_n$ is increasing.  3) $\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}$ is *decreasing*.  So $a_{n+1} < - 1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} <0$ so $a_n$ is bounded.  Furthermore $a_{n} < \lim a_m \le  \lim -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{m}} = -1 - 0 = -1$.  So $a_n$ is bounded by $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may use, for $k\ge1$,
$$
 2\sqrt{k+1}-2\sqrt{k}= \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{k}-2\sqrt{k-1}.
$$ Then, by summing from $k=1$ to $k=n-1$ terms telescope giving
$$
 2\sqrt{n}-2<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{n-1}, \quad n\ge2.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a new BS.c candidate and did not learn integrals yet. I need to use the basic theorems and lemmas from the Calculus course syllabus (what has been taught so far)

Comment: @AlexˢᵅˢʰᵅDruzina Ok, then induction is a direct way. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it was told that $a_n$ converges to $-2<L<-1$ so I tried to show by induction that $a_n$ is bounded by $-1$, but I'm always stuck with $a_{n+1} \le -1 + 1/\sqrt{n}$ or something like that.

Comment: To prove by induction$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{n-1} ,\quad n\ge2,$$ leads to $$2\sqrt{n-1}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}} <2\sqrt{n}.$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how that would help me :(
Can you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 1):

Note: To prove something converges you don't *have* to figure out what it converges to.  And to prove something is bounded above you don't *have* to find the *least* upper bound; it's enough just to find *any* upper bound (and prove it is an upper bound).

So

$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n+1} + 2\sqrt{n}$.

Claim: $2\sqrt n + \frac 1{\sqrt n} > 2\sqrt{n+1}$ for all natural $n$.

Pf: As all terms are positive and greater than zero...

$2\sqrt n + \frac 1{\sqrt n} > 2\sqrt{n+1} \iff$

$(2\sqrt n + \frac 1{\sqrt n})^2 > (2\sqrt{n+1})^2 \iff $

$4 n + 4 + \frac 1n > 4(n+1) \iff$

$\frac 1n > 0$.

So it it is true.

And so $a_{n+1} - a_n = 2\sqrt{n} + \frac 1{\sqrt n} - 2\sqrt{n+1} > 0$ so $a_{n+1} > a_n$.

So $\{a_i\}$ is monotonically increasing.

Claim:  $a_{n} \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}} \le 0$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Base case: $a_2 = 1 - 2\sqrt{2} \le 1-2 = -1 < -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{1}} \le 0$.

Inductive step:

If $a_n \le -1 +\frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}}$ then

$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n} + 2\sqrt{n-1}$

$\le -1 +\frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}}+ \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n} + 2\sqrt{n-1}$

We proved above that $\frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}}- 2\sqrt{n} + 2\sqrt{n-1} > 0$ so

$a_{n+1} \le  -1 +\frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}}+ \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n} + 2\sqrt{n-1} < -1 +\frac 1{\sqrt{n}} < -1 + 1 = 0$.

So the claim is true.

$a_n \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n-1}} \le 0$ so $\{a_i\}$ is bounded above by $0$.

Claim 2:  $\{a_i\}$ is bounded above by $-1$.

Claim:  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $\frac 1{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon \iff n > \frac 1{\epsilon^2}$.

So for all  $n + 1 > \frac 1{\epsilon^2}$ then $a_{n+1} \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{n}} < - 1 + \epsilon$.  But as $\{a_i\}$ is monotonically increasing.  If $m \le n \le \frac 1{\epsilon^2} -1$ then $a_m < a_{n+1} < -1 + \epsilon$ and if $n \ge n+1 >  \frac 1{\epsilon^2}$ then $a_m \le -1 + \frac 1{\sqrt{m-1}} < -1 + \epsilon$.

So all $a_i < 1 + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So $a_i \le -1$.

And $\{a_i\}$ is monotonically increasing.

So $\{a_i\}$ converges.

That's it.  Now, I don't have any idea what it converges to.  My proof was crude and ham-fisted.  But it *was* a legitimate proof.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence by the Hermite-Hadamard inequality

$$ 2\sqrt{n}-2=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\tag{1} $$

$$ 2\sqrt{n-1/2}-\sqrt{2}= \int_{1/2}^{n-1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\tag{2}$$
and by rearranging
$$ -\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)\leq\left(-2\sqrt{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right) \leq -\left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right).\tag{3}$$
Actually 
$$ \left(-2\sqrt{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right) \stackrel{\text{CT}}{=} -2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})^2}}_{\Theta(k^{-3/2})}\stackrel{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\zeta\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=-1.4603545\ldots\tag{4}$$
where $\text{CT}$ stands for *creative telescoping*.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With a [Riemann Zeta Function Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8):

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{1 + {1 \over \root{2}} + \cdots + {1 \over \root{n - 1}} - 2\root{n}}} =
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{k}} - {1 \over \root{n}}} - 2\root{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \root{n}} + \pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{k}} - 2\root{n}} =
-\,{1 \over \root{n}} + \bracks{\zeta\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{0 < {1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x <
> {1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{3/2}} = {1 \over \root{n}}
> \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\Large\to}\,\,\, {\large 0}}$.

such that
$$
\bbx{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{1 + {1 \over \root{2}} + \cdots + {1 \over \root{n - 1}} - 2\root{n}}}} = \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}
$$